# Encode æ ø å from string

Tags: c#, encoding

I have a string which contains different signs instead of showing the danish æ ø å format.

example:

```
string s = "Jeg har et kv\u00c6g"
```

should be

```
string s = "Jeg har et kvæg"
```

Its a massive string containing many other different types. How do i encode this the correct way? I have tried with a simple replace, but that does not work.

eg. `strInput = strInput.Replace("\u00c6", "Æ");`

Look at this picture how my string looks. Even with the suggestion it does not work:
[image]

Comment: `\u00c6` is an [escape sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char); it's identical to writing the Unicode character 00C6, which is "Æ". Are you asking for a way to change *the source code* to use "Æ" instead of the escape sequence? Because at runtime they should be identical.

Comment: @JoeSewell Yes that was my intention - Sorry if that was not clear!

Comment: @JohnnyMopp as you can see in my edit this doesnt work either

Comment: Offensive comment - `@"\u00c6"` and `"\u00c6"` are two very different stings as you've found reading about string literals.

Comment: If the backslashes are part of the string try `e = Regex.Unescape(d);`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp it says invalid pattern

Answer (score 0):

To unescape escaped characters (i.e. get original representation), use Regex.Unescape()

```
string text = @"Jeg har et kv\u00c6g"; 
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Unescape(text)); // out --> Jeg har et kvÆg
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yGEhw6

**UPDATE**

Regex.Unescape() can throw two exceptions: ArgumentException (unrecognized escape sequence) and ArgumentNullException (source string is null), and if the data is not properly escaped you will get an error.

```
\dr\u00f8jdal\ Just Dr\u00f8jdal    <-- your string
\\dr\u00f8jdal\\ Just Dr\u00f8jdal  <-- properly escaped string (expected by Regex)
```

The workaround depends on the need, for example, you can Unescape() only certain pattern

```
out = Regex.Replace(in, @"\\u00[a-z][0-9]", m => Regex.Unescape(m.Value));
```

where `\\u00[a-z][0-9]` will catch all occurences of strings like "\u00c6", "\u00f8", etc. but ignore single "\". Note, the pattern might depend on used characters and you can adjust it if some of your characters will not be replaced.

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GDEN8k

Comment: Thanks but maybe something is wrong with my string cause i get invalid pattern?

Comment: Not sure what pattern do you mean. If I take a string from the screenshot, e.g. \u00f8, it results to correct ø, see the demo link above. Note @-prefix.

Comment: @SqlKindaGuy Is the example you've given in your question's text different than the string you're actually trying to get working? If that's the case, and the actual string has additional punctuation used by the Regex engine, that could cause the error you report.

Comment: @JoeSewell Well, the acutal string is above 25.000 linies, so yes there could be some "xtra" things inside it. But i cannot post the entire string, that would be too much

Comment: we won't be able to help you if we don't know exact sample source text and exact exception. Regex.Unescape() can throw two exceptions: ArgumentException (unrecognized escape sequence) and ArgumentNullException (source string is null) and both are nothing to do with a pattern (as there is no pattern as an argument in that method). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape

Comment: What about Encoding.UTF8.GetByes? Can that help me?

Comment: Does the above code `Console.WriteLine(Regex.Unescape(@"Jeg har et kv\u00c6g")` work as expected and has answered your question? If true, nope, Encoding.UTF8 will not help. If false, give an example that will clarify the problem. You might need to split your long string into lines, loop through them and find what line "does not work".

Comment: ahh okay - its complaing about this string: \dr\u00f8jdal\ Just Dr\u00f8jdal

Comment: that string is not properly escaped due to single "\" around first word, see updated answer